# AOL IE9/FF4 user unable to download some images (random)

Tags: firefox, load, internet-explorer-9, aol

I have a user on my site which (AOL + IE9) which is having issues with images on a webpage not loading. It's odd because I can't replicate the issue whatsoever. He mentions that the problem also occurs in Firefox. Basically, the page will load but some of the images on the page don't load even though the images do exist and we (and many other users) can view the pages without any problem. Also, sometimes a particular page will load images while other times it wont.

Any ideas? I've tried all the troubleshooting I can think of:

- Check add ons
- Has highspec computer
- Check antivirus/firewall/etc software might be blocking
- decent internet connection
- no issues with when running a tracert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is he behind a proxy that might block certain traffic? Does he run an anti-spyware tool which might modify his %SYSTEM32%/drivers/etc/Hosts file - and does it work if he changes that back to defaults?

If you can get him to download Firebug in Fx he can go to Net->Images which might help explain why the request for the images failed.